# How to make input placeholder font-size different from input value font-size

Tags: html, css

I am in a situation where the required placeholder text for an input field is too long for the width of the field. To solve this, I am trying to give the placeholder a smaller `font-size`. It seems that no matter what I do, I cannot make the `font-size` of the placeholder text different than the value text. I've tried throwing `!important` on one, both, and neither with no luck.

My React code:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="inputId"
  name="inputName"
  placeholder="A long string of text that does not fit"
  onChange={props.handleChange}
  value={props.someValue}
  className={styles.myClass}
/>
```

My CSS:

```
.myClass {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 66.8125px !important;
}

.myClass::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
  font-size: 1em;
}

.myClass:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
  font-size: 1em;
}

.myClass::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-size: 1em;
}

.myClass:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the cause is `em` units. I changed to `px` and it does work -> https://jsfiddle.net/dbagu2n7/1/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your placeholder font-size value is relative to the font-size of its *containing* element, so 1em is just going to be the same size as the font-size for the text input:

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.myClass {
    font-size: 2em; /* 2em -> body font-size * 2 -> 20px * 2 = 40px */
    height: 66.8125px !important;
}

.myClass::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    font-size: 1em; /* 1em -> input font-size * 1 -> 40px * 1 = 40px */
}

.myClass:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    font-size: 1em;
}

.myClass::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
     font-size: 1em;
}

.myClass:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Setting the value to a fraction of 1 does the trick:

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw1rf1h9/)

```
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.myClass {
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 66.8125px !important;
}

.myClass::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

.myClass:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

.myClass::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
     font-size: 0.5em;
}

.myClass:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Give `:placeholder-shown` a try:

```css
input {
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 66.8125px !important;
  width: 150px;
}

input:placeholder-shown {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputId" name="inputName" placeholder="A long string of text that does not fit" />
```

Comment: thanks this the the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `:placeholder` pseudo-element is, effectively, a child of the input.

As such, `1em` will equal `2em` as that this is the **inherited** font-size.

**1em is the same as 100% of the parent font-size**

If you want the pseudo-element's font size to be half of the parent, use `font-size:50%`.